# WHERE condition to exclude amounts with decimals ending with '0's or '5's

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

I have a column 'amount' with decimals. I am trying to exclude rows where the amount value ends either with '0's or '5's.

How can I achieve that...

Column type: decimal (7,2)

**Ex: numbers to exclude**

```
10.25
11.20
100.00
```

Comment: What is the data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
 WHERE (CAST(your_field * 100 AS INTEGER) % 5) <> 0
```

But it is hard to tell without more detail on your data type.  Also there can be funky rounding issues with floating point values.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg yes with decimal mine will work.  so will gordan's.  not sure which would be faster.  probably gordan's since I have a cast... of course a bad optimizer would choke on the not in.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting way to do this uses "modular" arithmetic

```
where col % 0.1 not in (0.00, 0.05)
```

The `%` operator works on non-integer bases as well as integer ones.

Comment: More than interesting it is brilliant.  Truly rarefied thinking.

Answer (score 0):

What I did here is changed the number into a string, trimmed off the trailing blanks, and then reversed the string to take the first character to see if it was no 1 or 5

```
SELECT * into #test FROM (SELECT CAST(10.25 as decimal(7,2)) as val UNION SELECT 8.21 UNION SELECT 6.00) DQ 

select * from #test WHERE LEFT(REVERSE(RTRIM(CAST(val as nvarchar(50)))),1) NOT IN ('5', '0')

drop table #test
```

Comment: While this approach will work it is a very very slow way to solve this problem.